# How does Magento 2 adjust the prices when configurable options clicked

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options

How does Magento 2 adjust the prices when configurable options clicked?

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how the price is getting changed or figure out which event listener gets called when those checkboxes are checked but so far had no luck.

Comment: Is this custom module?

Comment: No, default Magento, but the theme is custom.